# What is the Weth contract address

Tags: ether

Hello can someone tell me the weth contract address to use when swapping exact eth for tokens on etherscan.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following addresses concern the ERC20 token WETH (Wrapped Ether):

[Mainnet Ethereum] WETH address: `0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2`

[Ropsten Testnet] WETH address: `0xc778417E063141139Fce010982780140Aa0cD5Ab`

[Rinkeby Testnet] WETH address: `0xc778417E063141139Fce010982780140Aa0cD5Ab`

[Kovan Testnet] WETH address: `0xd0A1E359811322d97991E03f863a0C30C2cF029C`

Comment: What's your source?